# Speeding up FCKEditor

Tags: javascript, optimization, fckeditor, minify

Does anyone have a technique for speeding up the FCKEditor?  Are there some key JavaScript files that can be minified or removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In it's newest version (3.0.1) the FCKEditor has been renamed to [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Read about some of the [performance optimisations](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_Loading_performance_details) that have been done

Comment: Check the link for CKEditor - I think you pasted the url incorrectly.